# Why is CoinbaseWalletConnector not working (wagmi)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is CoinbaseWalletConnector not working (wagmi)?

I use the **wagmi** library to create a dap, Wallet connect does not connect during work. All other wallets work correctly, Wallet connect gives an error.

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at Object.__ (QRCode.js:27:1)
```

[enter image description he](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIQcz.png)

App.

In App I import all the **necessary modules,** creating a **client**

```
//App

import { WagmiConfig, createClient } from "wagmi";
import { configureChains } from "wagmi";
import { avalanche, bsc, mainnet } from '@wagmi/core/chains'

import { infuraProvider } from "wagmi/providers/infura";
import { publicProvider } from "wagmi/providers/public";

import { CoinbaseWalletConnector } from "wagmi/connectors/coinbaseWallet";
import { MetaMaskConnector } from "wagmi/connectors/metaMask";
import { WalletConnectConnector } from 'wagmi/connectors/walletConnect'

// API key for Ethereum node
// Two popular services are Infura (infura.io) and Alchemy (alchemy.com)
const infuraId = process.env.INFURA_ID;
const defaultChains = [mainnet, avalanche, bsc]

// Configure chains for connectors to support
const { chains } = configureChains(defaultChains, [
    infuraProvider({ infuraId }),
    publicProvider(),
]);

// Set up connectors
export const connectors = [
    new CoinbaseWalletConnector({
        chains,
        options: {
            appName: "wagmi demo",
            qrcode: true,
        },
    }),
    new WalletConnectConnector({
        chains,
        options: {
            infuraId,
            qrcode: true,
        },
    }),
    new MetaMaskConnector({
        chains,
    }),
];
const client = createClient({
    autoConnect: false,
    connectors,
});

function App() {

  return (
    <>
        <WagmiConfig client={client}>
            <Home />     
        </WagmiConfig>
    </>
  );
}
```

My component

In my main component I write **onclick()** to handle **wallets**

```
//My component

import { useConnect } from "wagmi";

const Component = (props) => {
    const { connect, connectors } = useConnect();
    return (
        <>
            <WalletButton img={metaMask}
                                              title={"MetaMask"}
                                              onPress={() => { connect({ connector: connectors[2] }) }}
                                />

                                <WalletButton img={coinbase}
                                              title={"Coinbase wallet"}
                                              onPress={() => { connect({ connector: connectors[0] }) }}
                                />

                                <WalletButton img={walletConnectImg}
                                              title={"Wallet connect"}
                                              onPress={() => { connect({ connector: connectors[1] }) }}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

Who faced a similar problem? Help XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. It is because Buffer module was included in webpack before therefore, by default you could use that module in react. Now, you have to either add it using webpack plugins or in my case there was no webpack.config file because we are using some other libraries. And, I didn't know how to add it so I used a temporary solution as:

1. Install Buffer library
   `npm install buffer`
2. I added this in app.jsx file
   `window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require("buffer").Buffer;`